# How to call a collection from a dynamic action in oracle apex18.1

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a requirement to refresh one interactive report when user click on Refresh button and I need to generate that report from a collection.
I have created a collection in the process which is in pre-rendering region:

[image]

but when I am clicking on Refresh Button(button is in adifferent region) it is not calling( also I created a dynamic action in button and have written collection code in that too).

If someone knows this how to do this..please let me know. Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Run your code in debug mode; if your dynamic action fires, the debug log should show it calling your code. Show your dynamic action and the code it executes.

Comment: Is dynamic action called from a button click? Let us see your dynamic action

Comment: Do you need to refresh the collection and then refresh the report based on the collection?

Answer (score 0):

change your process to be executed on ajax callback and then make your ajax request as following

```
apex.server.process(
'your process name',                             // Process or AJAX Callback name
{}, 
{
  success: function (pData) {             // Success Javascript
    apex.event.trigger( "#myRegionStaticID", "apexrefresh" );
  },
  dataType: "text"                        // Response type (here: plain text)
}
```

);